# How to get variables to my program vrom text file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, crop

I have a file like:

---

- a [able%5:00:00:capable:00] [able] capable
- a [abnormal%3:00:00::] [abnormal]
- a [absent%3:00:00::] [absent]
- a [absolute%3:00:00::] [absolute] perfect or complete
- a [abstract%3:00:00::] [abstract] existing only in the mind
- a [abundant%3:00:00::] [abundant] plentiful

---

I want to get first column "avle", "abnormal" etc to my object. How to crop them and how storage them?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? I would recommend looking at [`regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

Comment: I thought that this is some typical file like csv or something :/

Comment: Because i only know c++ and php

Comment: Sadly i haven't heard about Flex or Bison.

Comment: I need only word "able" from line: a [able%5:00:00:capable:00] [able] capable

Comment: @Tanuki This question is off-topic. Please don't enable people who ask off-topic gimme-teh-codez questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the string tokenizer, the best/easiest way to split a line into different variables.

```
char* word = strtok(line," [%:]");
char* word2 = strtok(0," [%:]");
int value = strtoi(strtok(0," [%:]"));
```

to store there is a vector container, but there can be used any type of arrays, what is more convenient